# How to output this template in Python

Tags: python

How to output this template in Python

Can this be done with the for loop?

[image]

This is my experiment so far

```
num = int(input())
for item in range(0,num+1):
    for i in range(item,0,-1):
        print(i,end=' ')
    print("\r")
```

Comment: Do you want this as the final output from some earlier processing?  What you've tried - can you share?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This seems like a homework question and it would be useful if you could show in good faith what effort you've put into solving this. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to output like the screenshot, there are multiple approaches to this. such as, you can do something like this.

Here outer loop controls the number of lines and the inner loop iterates through powers of 2 and prints them.

```py
n = 8

for i in range(n):
    j = 2**i
    while j >= 1:
        print(j, end='\t')
        j = j//2
    print()
```

If you want to achieve it only with `for` loop you can do this like:

```py
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i, -1, -1):
        print(2**j, end='\t')
    print()
```

Comment: Can you give a very brief explanation about your code?
For example, why did you use (mathematical) power?

Comment: the pattern is the powers of 2. If we see the last line, it is a series of 2^7, 2^6, 2^5 up to 2^0. that's why, I used power of 2 here